# ¿Cómo poner como default la red de ethernet y no la de dockerNat cuando use localhost?

Tags: react-native, docker

Ahora mismo react-native usa la red dockerNet, pero mi dirección de mi red ethernet es 192.168.x.x  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que necesito tener mi docker encendido y hacer las pruebas con mi teléfono en mi red local

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a un servicio (puerto) que se esta ejecutando en tu contenedor Docker, NO necesitas configurar ninguna red.

Lo que tienes que hacer es "abrir" un puerto.

Si por ejemplo, tu aplicación esta usando el puerto 9000 puedes publicar ese puerto en el 80 del host:

```
docker run -p 80:9000 mi_aplicacion
```

Con esto tu aplicacion estara en la IP del host donde se este ejecutando tu contenedor Docker. [Aquí tienes mas información](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)

Y [aquí una guía](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) de las gestión de puertos en Docker